# Unique representation of each point in 3d space by Linear combination of 3 mutually perpendicular vectors.

Tags: geometry, vectors, 3d

I intuitively accepted that there is an unique representation of any point in a 3d space by linear combination of 3 mutually perp. vectors. But now I'm wondering is this an axiom or a theorem?

If theorem where can I find a proof of this?

Just so that it is easier for you to explain - I'm a highschool student who knows vector addition, subtraction, scalar product and vector product and some basic knowledge or 3d geometry line equations of lines and planes.

Comment: This is not an axiom. It is true for inner product spaces over R3 and C3 though, meaning it is provable from the axioms of inner product spaces and vector spaces. It is possible to show that non-zero orthogonal vectors must be linearly independent, and that three linearly independent vectors span a three dimensional space, meaning that each vector in the space can be written as a linear combination of those three vectors.

Comment: Also, see any book on finite dimensional vector spaces, like the one by Halmos.